# error shown as Unknown column in field list while using Join Query in Query Builder

Tags: mysql, node.js, query-builder

I have set the Join query for the two tables using the Query Builder in Node.js. But I face the issue while trying to set table name with * as (cities.*)

Query Builder query as

```
const data = await qb.select('cities.*,s.state_name').where(where1)
                .join('states s', 's.state_id=cities.state_id').get('cities');
```

Error:

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
errno: 1054,
sqlMessage: 'Unknown column \'cities.*\' in \'field list\'',
sqlState: '42S22',
index: 0,
sql: 'SELECT `cities`.`*`, `s`.`state_name` FROM `cities` JOIN `states` `s` ON `s`.`state_id` = `cities`.`state_id` WHERE `cities`.`status` = 1' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = await qb.select('cities.*,s.state_name',false).where(where1)
            .join('states s', 's.state_id=cities.state_id').get('cities');
```

Try this with writing the false in an argument it will not do an auto-escape the field names.